# How do I load/use substances with libgdx?

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx

I've been looking at some substances (.sbsar file format) but I have no clue how to load or use these files. The links I find brings me to Unity & Unreal Engine, but if I search up anything related to libgdx or opengl, I can't get any results.
Does anyone know how I can use these textures in my libgdx java game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX isn't as advanced in 3D as Unreal Engine 4 by a long shot. Substances do not exist in LibGDX, you can use the `Material` for this. Out of the box it comes with Difuse, Specular, Glow, Reflection and some other maps. I think you need to roll your own shader for something like a normal map. LibGDX simply does not offer you the power UE4 does with shaders so if you want to create high-end 3D models and environments I would leave LibGDX and go with something like UE4.